# How to check Video is working or not in android?

Tags: android, video, playback

I have one list and in this list I set the list of videos,
some video playing and some is not working. So I want to have a message(like video is not working) when video is not working or not playing.

How I check video is working or not ?
And I play this video URL in videoview.

Comment: check duration of video. if duration is greater than 0 then that video will work.

Comment: @illango..thanks ..but some my video is like this type of url:http://www.youtube.com/v/T_9zpAWFFKQ?f=standard&app=youtube_gdata      and that video are not working in device so what i do?

Comment: the above linked video is too big.

Comment: llango..yes i know but i want to play it at any position so any way for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If video is not working there are two reasons.
First the video's size is bigger then device and second, video is properly not working.